# Trim down an excel formula?

Tags: excel, formula

Hey I'm trying to get my excel formula to fit in to a data validation formula, which after a little research I'm finding has a 255 character limit.  Mine has 277 characters, and I feel like it's got some redundancies, but I'm not advanced enough to figure out how to trim this heffer down.  Can anyone out there help?

```
=IF(AND(H11="Embryo",G11<>"F2"),INDIRECT("'"&C11&"'"&"!$g$24:$g$27"),IF(AND(H11="Seed",G11<>"F2"),INDIRECT("'"&C11&"'"&"!$h$24:$h$27"),IF(AND(H11="Seed",G11="F2"),INDIRECT("'"&C11&"'"&"!$g$117:$g$120"),IF(AND(H11="Embryo",G11="F2"),INDIRECT("'"&C11&"'"&"!$h$117:$h$120"),E2))))
```

Comment: This is trying to return an array but it will only return the value of the first cell in the array.  Is it part of a larger array formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you always include the cell `C11` inside an `INDIRECT` please consider the following formula that places the `INDIRECT` outside while the conditionals just return the range addresses as strings.

```
=INDIRECT("'"&C11&"'"&IF(AND(H11="Embryo",G11<>"F2"),"!$g$24:$g$27",IF(AND(H11="Seed",G11<>"F2"),"!$h$24:$h$27",IF(AND(H11="Seed",G11="F2"),"!$g$117:$g$120",IF(AND(H11="Embryo",G11="F2"),"!$h$117:$h$120",E2)))))
```

Please note that this logic will break if none of the conditions are met. Regards,

Comment: Nice! I still do not see what the OP is trying here by trying to return an array to one cell.  But this is probably as simple as it will get.

Comment: I agree but I've stopped trying to figure peoples questions out. Cheers

Comment: Thanks @nbayly ! some things got flipped but it will work perfectly = )

Comment: Glad I could help. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking some of the parts of your formula and defining names for those regions of your sheet this way you can condense long strings into small words greatly reducing the length of your formula. Could help a great deal. Also will make your formula more readable to you down the road when you find yourself having to debug it.

Comment: I don't know if this would work as the larger ranges are inside an `INDIRECT`. When it resolves the formula it would replace the named ranges for its `.Value` rather than its `.Address`. Anyone disagrees?

Comment: Sure it would just break the calculation down into segments and place the name location at the sum point then place that in the base calculation. In this way you can make much larger formals that far exceed the basic character limit.

Comment: My problem is not with what was said as much as this is a comment more than it is an answer.